# Bootstraped t-test with permuted p-values

Tags: r

I would like to do a bootstraped t-test with permuted p-values. I have two unequal samples (first sample with 80 individuals and second with 35). Can anybody help with code? I'm a begginer in statistics, and don't understand how I can do this.

```
library(readxl)
rain <- read_excel('rain.xlsx')
mix <- read_excel('mix.xlsx')
rain       mix
0.738      1.50
0.725      2.13
2.64       2.46
0.877      1.52  
1.61       1.47
1.48       ...
1.45 
1.51 
1.89 
0.48 
...
```

Comment: A reproducible example would help...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks, I did it myself, the question is not actual